# Переменные php в мета тегах

Tags: php, meta

Ситуация такая: в php имеются переменная:

```
$discription = 'Описание';
```

Для каждой страницы свое значение.
Как правильно вставить переменную в мета тег?
В конструкции вида:

```
<meta name="discription" content= $discription >
```

$discription отображается как строка. Подскажите, как в content получить значение переменной. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: В английском языке нет слова discription, есть description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если файл с расширением php:

```
<meta name="discription" content="<?= $discription ?>">
```

Comment: Без двойных кавычек тоже работает:
<meta name="discription" content= <?= $discription ?> >

Answer (score 2):

Смотря как вы выводите, если сразу в скрипте то так:

```
echo '<meta name="discription" content= ' . $discription . ' >';
```

Либо так:

```
echo "<meta name='discription' content= $discription >";
echo "<meta name='discription' content= {$discription} >";
```

А лучше всего использовать `шаблонизаторы`. Т.к. например будет у вас строка вида:
`content = "$discription"` При этом `$discription = '123"456';`, то имеем на выходе: `content = "123"456"`, Как видите, уже будет работать некорректно.

Comment: Спасибо всем за советы, все заработало!